# is there short cut to switch between two different android studio instances

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

Having two androidStudios open for two different projects,
is there a key short cut to toggle/switch between these two (bring one of them into foreground)?

Comment: you meant ALT + TAB to toggle between instances ? or Command + ~ for osX ?

Comment: looking for Mac's.  but those short cut does not bring the other androidStudio into foreground.

Comment: Cmd ⌘ + TAB (to toggle between two different apps), Cmd ⌘ + ` (to toggle between two windows of the same app). note it's ` (the one with ~) not ' (single quote)

Comment: do have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193938/239688

Comment: thanks@angel Koh! the cmd+` does switching among the android studio apps,  except if there are more than three apps, it will loop not toggle. But it's better than always using mouse.  If you could put it as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use

> Cmd ⌘ + TAB (to toggle between two different apps) and
>
> Cmd ⌘ + ` (to toggle between two windows of the same app)

. note it's ` (the one with ~) not ' (single quote)